# How do we want to divvy up blog posts for the materials received from the Promotional Grants?

Tags: discussion, blog, promotional-grant

Super Soldier @BrettWhiteΨ has provided opportunities for a few of the people on this site with materials for promoting SciFi and StackExchange itself.

Since most/all of these items would be great subjects for blog posts, I was wondering how we wanted to devide up the posting assignments.

I'm sure everyone chosen/participating in these Grants want to write a blog post (especially as a thanks for the awesome swag), it might get a little confusing who is supposed to write about what if all of the participants are getting the same materials.

Answer (score 3):

**Divide and Conquer**

Everyone who participates in a Grant should somehow (through emails or a separate room in the chat) decide what exactly they will cover in their respective blog entries. This would prevent duplicate blog posts.

Answer (score 2):

**Free Reign**

No restrictions.

People blog what they will and we deal with any overlap.

Answer (score 2):

I think we should do blog posts on the following topics, and divide it out, for the Star Wars.

1. General review as a newbie
2. General Review as an enthusists
3. Review as a guy who's watched the series, but not too often.
4. Review of the extra goodies
5. Commentary reviews, if they have them.

I say let's post them in the order they are ready, every 2 days, until they are all done. We can all pick one of the topics to work on (2 if required). Multiple people can contribute if desired as well.

Basically, it comes down to this, find as many reasonable blog posts as can be found, and write them up. If there's only one review that could really be had (Especially in books, etc), then just post the one review combined together, otherwise, break it out as required.

Comment: My question was generic for any swag that would be sent out to more than one member, not just the Star Wars BluRays.

Comment: Good point. Hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

**Combined blog posts**

Each participant writes their opinion on the subject matter, and those opinions get combined into 1 blog post.

Maybe making a SciFi.SE user on blogoverflow.com for this so everyone will get credit for what they write.